# Why $f(z)=z^2$ is single valued?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why  $f(z)=z^2$ is single valued where $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

From definition we have

$$z^2=e^{2 \log z}=e^{2(\ln|z|+i(2k\pi+Arg(z)))}$$

I dont get it ;/ Maybe it's getting late.

Comment: It is a function, the same as $z \mapsto z\cdot z$. How can it be multiply valued?

Comment: Because the arguments of all the possible multiple values differ by integral multiples of $2\pi$. That's why raising a complex number to an integral power always produces a unique value.

Comment: My book says: $z^w:=exp(w \log z)$

Comment: You are right, @luka5z. But it is only for nonintegral exponents that there can be more than one distinct result. It's because $2\pi kw$ is an integral multiple of $2\pi$ for all integral $k$ if and only if $w$ is an integer.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Integer powers of nonzero complex numbers are defined by repeated multiplication or division..." So $z^2$ is simply $z*z = Re(z)^2 - Im(z)^2 + 2i Re(z) Im(z)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of definition.

Normally, $z^a$ with $a \in \mathbb Z$ *can* be defined as a single-valued function without drawbacks, so we do so; it is not defined as $\exp(a \log z)$ but as $z \cdot \dots \cdot z$ $a$ times. (or if $a$ is negative $\frac 1z \cdot \dots \cdot \frac 1z$ $a$ times)

Instead, $z^a$ with $a \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Z$ admits multiple values; in particular, if $a = m/n$ it has $n$ distinct values, while if $a$ is irrational then it has infinite multiple values. (This comes of course from the fact that the complex logarithm is a polydrome function)

There is no ambiguity though, because if $a \in \mathbb Z$ we have that $\exp(a \log z) = z^a$ (as defined above); in particular $\exp(a \log z)$ admits a single value.

Comment: In fact, it *is* defined as $\exp(a\log z)$ even for $a\in\mathbb Z$, but it still gives the same result.

Comment: Yes, but in particular $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{C}$ so definition should be valid. I think @MPW explained it

Comment: @MPW I'll add that to the answer, thanks :)